# cannot edit permission for a folder

Tags: security, permissions, windows-server-2008

I am using Windows Server 2008 x64. I login using administrator. I want to add a new user for read/write access for a folder under c:\windows\system32. I tried to select folder (right click), then select Property -> Security -> Edit under Security Tab, the Add button is greyed out. Why? Any programming based or other quick solutions?

I tried the same operation under other non-windows system folder, it is ok to add new user to permission.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder doesn't give administrator permission to edit the folder's settings then administrator can't edit the folder's settings.

One answer that would belong on Server Fault is that if administrator can take ownership of the folder then administrator can edit the folder's settings to give administrator permission to edit the folder's settings (this part seems recursive).

Programmatically, you could write a program which would edit the folder's settings.  If administrator executes the program, it will still fail.  If administrator installs the program as a service, to execute under the Local System account, the program will have a better chance of success.

Comment: "administrator can take ownership of the folder" -- how?

Comment: In the file's properties, security settings.